# can I svn merge without always specifying the first revision?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, tracking, tagging

The pickiest question I have ever posted to SO:

myproject/tags/production always contains the production-ready version of myproject. I merge sequential approved revisions from trunk into it like so, where N is the currently live rev, and M is the new desired rev:

cd tags/production
svn merge -r N:M ^/trunk
svn ci -m 'merging trunk through rxxxx to production

My question is, why do I always have to specify N? If I just use "-r M" I get "svn: Second revision required". But N is always the same as my previous M, and I thought the point of merge tracking (we are running svn 1.6) was so that svn remembers the revisions you already merged..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't try it myself but, according to subversion documentation, [the `merge`command is smart enough to include only not previously merged changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.advancedsyntax).

But if you don't want to include all trunk revisions you could try:

```
svn merge -r 0:M ^/trunk
```

It should merge changes not already merged into your working copy **up to revision M**.

Comment: +1 You can also just omit the revision range entirely, and Subversion will simply merge all revisions that are eligible for merging.

Comment: @Wim: yes, it's right, but it looks like rob needs to merge only *sequential approved revisions from trunk*.

Comment: @Antonio: correct, I'm just pointing out the feature because many people don't realize that you can omit the revision range.

Comment: Right, that works well when we want to branch ALL new trunk revisions to a branch. With no revisions svn gives us everything from the last-merged-revision to the HEAD. But in this case we want the last-merged-revision to whatever number I specify.

Comment: Hold the phone, somehow I did not see Antonio's original post here until just now. That's exactly it, success!! (Seems so obvious in retrospect, but I never would have thought of it)

Comment: An even more concise alternative: `svn merge ^/trunk@M`

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, Subversion could do what you're asking and allow automatic merging up to a specified point. Probably the problem is that "-r M" means a single revision M, whereas merging is an operation on a range of revisions. Implicitly converting a single-revision type parameter to a revision-range parameter does not sound like a good idea.

Subversion should do merge tracking just fine if revisions are not specified manually.

Comment: The svn client reports syntax error and asks for second revision number. So the problem is not that it tries to merge a single revision.

Comment: No, for a single revision the syntax `-c N` is used.